# IndentationError in my python script

Tags: python

my python version is 2.7.2, and my OS is win XP.

this is my script:

```
import sqlite3
import os
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
     abort, render_template, flash

DATABASE = 'C:\Python27\flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

def connect_db(): return sqlie3.connect(app.config['DATABASE']  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The error came up when I was running it as a module with python shell.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Right at the  “：” is the place where the idle gave the error message that there's a invalid syntax.
But I can hardly find out any syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed to close one parenthesis at:

```
def connect_db(): return sqlie3.connect(app.config['DATABASE']
```

It should be:

```
def connect_db(): return sqlie3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
```

And the reason it goes all the way to the `:` is that Python tries to interpret this as a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
def connect_db(): return sqlie3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'] if __name__ == '__main__': ...
```

But because `:` cannot be a part of a valid [boolean operation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) it gives you this lovely syntax error.

Comment: Oh， what an obvious error! I should be more careful with it.Thanks!